# Как бы "экономно" реализовать авторизацию с твиттером

Tags: oauth, twitter, php, long-poll, javascript

Пишу игру интегрированную с твиттером. php + js, сервер общается с клиентом через long polling, при этом сервер отдает примерно 1 ответ в 2 секунды одному клиенту. И разумеется я  стараюсь как можно больше экономить на таких ответах, передавая как можно меньше информации, чтоб не сильно забивать канал. И все шло хорошо пока не сделал систему авторизации. Авторизацию сделал через твиттер с помощью библиотеки [tmhOAuth](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth), при первой авторизации пользователя в приложении - мы записываем его token и token secret в базу. (изначально библиотеке они просто писались в сессию).
И теперь над чем я ломаю голову:
Если пользоваться стандартной системой авторизации твиттера, то при первой авторизации юзера кидает в твиттер, там он дает приложению права и его возвращает на сайт, в последующие разы при авторизации - идет запрос к твиттеру, НЕ просит права и тут же перенаправляет юзера обратно на сайт. Единственная проблема здесь - вот эта последующая авторизация происходит какое-то время, около 1-2 секунд - это нервирует, при этом необходимые токены у нас уже записаны в базе с первой авторизации, так что это по сути не необходимо.
Но. Очень очень не хочется возвращаться к старой стандартной теме на сайтах с авторизацией с паролями. В этом случае конечно же последующие разы авторизация происходила бы мгновенно, при наличии необходимых кук, хотя если юзера почемуто разлогинит - ему прийдется вводить пароль.. а это некрасиво и лишние телодвижения.

К тому же, в обоих случаях нужно хранить либо сессии, либо куки, либо и то и то, а они как известно отправляются ПРИ КАЖДОМ запросе на сервер и обратно, а это портит мне всю малину с long pollingом, т.к. ответы с сервера получаются в два/три раза больше.

Вот и думаю как бы сделать систему авторизации такой, чтобы и пароль вводить не нужно было, и чтобы не заставляло юзера долго ждать при авторизации, и чтоб куки и сессии были не сильно длинные, дабы канал не засорять...

Так вот, может ктото уже сталкивался с таким, и возможно кто-то нашел какое-то элегантное решение, либо возможно у кого-то просто есть хорошая идея как бы это можно было сделать покрасивее? Приветствуются любые идеи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не отправляя куки вы ни как не потвердите что вы есть вы так что придется смирится.

а по поводу того что приходится ждать и оно нервирует, то поставьте юзверю какую не будь картинку, отвлекающую или прогресбар, и он не будет нервничать.